# dpkg error message upgrading from ubuntu 15.04 to 15.10

Tags: upgrade, 15.04, dpkg, 15.10

I hope you can help me. I am upgrading to ubuntu 15.10 from 15.04 following the process described here http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/upgrade. **In the Installing the upgrades** process and almost at the end the process it got stuck with a error message **E:Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned and error code (1)**

If i try `sudo dpkg --configure -a` i get

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of evince:
 evince depends on evince-common (>= 3.16); however:
  Version of evince-common on system is 3.14.2-0ubuntu2.

dpkg: error processing package evince (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of brasero:
 brasero depends on brasero-common (= 3.12.1-0ubuntu2); however:
  Version of brasero-common on system is 3.12.0-0ubuntu2.

dpkg: error processing package brasero (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libbrasero-media3-1:
 libbrasero-media3-1 depends on brasero-common (= 3.12.1-0ubuntu2); however:
  Version of brasero-common on system is 3.12.0-0ubuntu2.

dpkg: error processing package libbrasero-media3-1 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder:
 rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder depends on libbrasero-media3-1 (>= 3.0.0); however:
  Package libbrasero-media3-1 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-desktop:
 ubuntu-desktop depends on evince; however:
  Package evince is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-desktop (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of brasero-cdrkit:
 brasero-cdrkit depends on libbrasero-media3-1 (= 3.12.1-0ubuntu2); however:
  Package libbrasero-media3-1 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package brasero-cdrkit (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 evince
 brasero
 libbrasero-media3-1
 rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder
 ubuntu-desktop
 brasero-cdrkit
```

That is what I am getting in the Upgrade Dialog

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try a `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: Tried but no success. I get the following message 

Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/brasero-common_3.12.1-0ubuntu2_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/evince-common_3.16.1-0ubuntu1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to perform a a fresh install and restore your data from backup.

You did perform a a backup before you started the upgrade ? If not, start with a backup.

If you wish to try to upgrade anyways, I suggest you remove all those broken packages.

```
sudo apt-get purge evince brasero libbrasero-media3-1 rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder ubuntu-desktop brasero-cdrkit
```

Then re-try your upgrade and re-install those packages after the upgrade.

```
sudo apt-get install evince brasero libbrasero-media3-1 rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder ubuntu-desktop brasero-cdrkit
```

If you get errors, you can try to manually remove the packages, one at a time if necessary

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-all evince
```

If you still get errors you will need to manually remove the package

```
cd /var/lib/dpkg/info
sudo rm evince.*
```

Re-run the upgrade, install the packages you removed

```
sudo apt-get install evince brasero libbrasero-media3-1 rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder ubuntu-desktop brasero-cdrkit
```

See the apt-get and dpkg man pages and/or http://blog.bodhizazen.com/linux/apt-get-how-to-fix-very-broken-packages/ for details on those commands.

Comment: I am trying to continue with the upgrade process, backup was already made it.  Do i need to close Distribution Upgrade dialog window in order to follow your recommendations?

Comment: Yes, close/abort the upgrade window.

Comment: I followed the recommendations i had to remove one by one. After I tried to install the packages again but at the end i get **Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/brasero-common_3.12.1-0ubuntu2_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/evince-common_3.16.1-0ubuntu1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)**

Comment: Do you think should i try the upgrading process again?

Comment: You have to manually remove the packages, then re-run the upgrade.

Comment: As pointed out, you could have done a fresh install by now ;)