# Error while upgrading from 15.04 to 15.10

Tags: upgrade, 15.04, 15.10, dpkg

while running the upgrade a pop-up window appeared with the message

"The upgrade has aborted. Your system could be in an unusable state. A 
recovery will run now (dpkg --configure -a)."

After clicking "Ok", I was waiting for >30 min but nothing happens, the distribution upgrade is just stuck, and I can't figure out what exactly the error is (see screenshot).

[Distribution Upgrade -- Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tTvo.png)

I found some similar problems e.g. [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/690654/dpkg-error-message-upgrading-from-ubuntu-15-04-to-15-10) or [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/701942/upgrading-ubuntu-15-10-error) but at least there was an error traceback, which I don't have.

Should I abort the distribution upgrade, then try manually fixing the packages and then reboot?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: o.k., apparently the distribution upgrade worked after all... after running "dpkg --configure -a" and "sudo apt-get install -f", I rebooted and have 15.10 working... a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the cache with -

```
sudo apt-get clean
```